# Programmatically set boxBackgroundMode to TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-textinputlayout

I just migrate from **com.android.support:design** to **com.google.android.material**.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

I have the troubles with set up boxBackgroundMode as an outline for **TextInputLayout** programmatically.

```
 val textInputLayout = TextInputLayout(this)
 textInputLayout.addView(EditText(this))

 textInputLayout.boxBackgroundMode = TextInputLayout.BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE
 textInputLayout.boxStrokeColor = Color.BLACK
 textInputLayout.boxBackgroundColor = Color.BLACK
 textInputLayout.setBoxCornerRadii(23f,23f,23f,23f)

 someParentLayout.addView(textInputLayout)
```

At the same time, I hadn't such problems with **com.android.support:design**.
Can someone suggest how to resolve or tell why for **com.google.android.material** it doesn't work.

P.S. It works by defining `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"` in xml but i need to do it programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
textInputLayout.addView(EditText(this))
```

Perform:

```
val editText = EditText(this)
editText.background = null
textInputLayout.addView(editText)
// Alternatively `textInputLayout.addView(EditText(this).apply { background = null })`
```

**Why?**

Excerpt from `TextInputLayout` sources:

```
  private boolean shouldUseEditTextBackgroundForBoxBackground() {
    // When the text field's EditText's background is null, use the EditText's background for the
    // box background.
    return editText != null
        && boxBackground != null
        && editText.getBackground() == null // <-- by default EditText has background
        && boxBackgroundMode != BOX_BACKGROUND_NONE;
  }
```