# Android: Style TextInputLayout from non Activity class

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I want to create a TextInputLayout with border using the style: R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox from a non activity class.

Below is sample code:

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(context, null, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox);

textInputLayout.setHint("My Hint");
textInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundMode(TextInputLayout.BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE);
textInputLayout.setBoxCornerRadii(5, 5, 5, 5);
TextInputEditText et = new TextInputEditText(textInputLayout.getContext());
textInputLayout.addView(et);
```

When I run this I get following crash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tsp.bonw, PID: 10121
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.getTopLeftCornerResolvedSize()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.setBoxCornerRadii(TextInputLayout.java:938)
```

My guess is I'm not able to set the style attribute: R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox to TextInputLayout from the non activity class.

If I remove the call setBoxCornerRadii, the TextInputLayout is shown correctly in my activity but without the box. I need TextInputLayout to show with the box.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you pass an activity context into this class?

Comment: I get the same error with an activity context too. I don't think that's it. I think it's a bug. Check these links.  https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1192 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567668/programmatically-set-boxbackgroundmode-to-textinputlayout

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not added the view to any layout yet, just created it.
Move call to setradius to after addView(), and the problem wil be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

set TextInputLayout style with context wrapper I think it should work.

```
val textInputLayout = TextInputLayout(
        ContextThemeWrapper(
            this,
            R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox
        )
    )
```

Comment: The API is used from non activity class, so "this" can not be used. I've tried this solution it does not work.

Comment: then maybe pass your "context" varaible?

Comment: Yes tested with passing context only.

Comment: On the first time itself had to run with context and it did not work. With passing "this" code will not compile.